# Setting queryset within forms.ModelChoiceField()

Tags: django, django-forms

The queryset for the 'jurisdiction' field is set below in the initialization. The queryset is dependent on the id that is passed in, which comes from a specific link that a user clicks. As a result, I can't define a singular queryset within the forms.ModelChoiceField(), but it seems that django requires me to do this.

```
class TaxForm (forms.ModelForm):  #Will be used for state tax and other taxes

    jurisdiction = forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=?????)

    class Meta:
        model = Tax
        exclude = ('user', 'taxtype',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):

        self.taxtype = kwargs.pop('taxtype',None)
        super(TaxForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

        if int(self.taxtype) == 1:
            self.fields['jurisdiction'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in State.objects.all()]
        elif int(self.taxtype) == 2:
            self.fields['jurisdiction'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in Country.objects.all()]
        else:
            self.fields['jurisdiction'].choices = [(t.id, t) for t in State.objects.none()]
```

How can I indicate that I want the jurisdiction field to be a dropdown, but not specify one queryset within the forms.ModelChoiceField()? Alternatively, how can I make the queryset that is referenced in forms.ModelChoiceField() refer to the queryset that I initialize based on the taxtype?

Thanks!

Here is my tax model

```
class Tax(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=None)
    jurisdiction = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    rate = models.DecimalField(max_digits=10, decimal_places=2)
    basis = models.CharField(max_length=120, null=True, blank=True)
    regnumber = models.CharField(max_length=200, null=True, blank=True)  #tax number that will appear on customer invoice
    taxtype = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True) # 0 is other, 1 is state, 2 is federal

    def __str__(self):
        return '{} - {}'.format(self.user, self.name)
```

Comment: just try following way forms.ModelChoiceField(queryset=None) and self.fields['jurisdiction'].queryset =State.objects.all()

Comment: This can't work, a ModelChoiceField needs to have a specific model as its target, because it represents an underlying ForeignKey. What does your model field look like? But in your code, since you're setting `choices` anyway, there doesn't seem to be any good reason to use a ModelChoiceField, you should use a simple ChoiceField.

Comment: I've updated my question to include my Tax model within models.py. Thanks again Daniel! Let me know if you still think I should use a ChoiceField.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As I mentioned, ModelChoiceField is not the right thing to do here. That's for allowing the user to choose from related items from a single model that will be saved into a ForeignKey. You don't have a ForeignKey, and what's more you're setting the `choices` attribute in your init rather than `queryset`. You should make it a plain ChoiceField with an empty `choices` parameter:

```
jurisdiction = forms.ChoiceField(choices=())
```

(For the sake of completeness: if you did need to use ModelChoiceField you can put anything you like into the `queryset` parameter when you're overwriting it in `__init__`, because it will never be evaluated. But managers have a `none` method which returns an empty queryset, so you could do `queryset=State.objects.none()`.)

Comment: Cool, thanks Daniel. I'll make these changes tonight and let you know if I have any issues. You should have a page where people can donate money to you for your excellent help. I'd make a donation :) Thanks again for all of your help!